# tabBarController multiple filters of the same table

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller and a table (with its referred detail view) of elements.
Each element is composed of
- ID
- Type
- Text

I would like to use my tabbarcontroller as a filter of Type. 
What's the best way to do this? do i need to create multiple times these viewcontrollers, or is there an easiest way?
I tried creating multiple views, but it does not seem the correct solution at all

Comment: Tab bar controllers are intended for navigational purposes.  This doesn't conform the human interface guidelines set by apple.

Comment: My app will be just a list of elements in three different section, and some "tutorial views".. The tabbar is used to navigate, but three of its views will be nearly identical.. ..Do i need to create three "different" views of The same view? This seems redundant..!

Comment: You don't have to create 3 view controllers if they do the same thing. You can use the same UIViewController for 3 tabs of the tab bar controller.

Comment: You can also use a simple UITabBar at the bottom of your UiViewController which contains a table view, and filter content based on the selected tab.

Comment: My tabbar needs to be out of the uiviewcontroller, since it has other items which don't refer to the table. 
Can you please tell me how can i use the same UIViewController for 3 tabs of the tab bar controller?? Thank you

Comment: try using predicates

Comment: Hi Frane, can you be more specific? Thank you